# My Link Crawler Coes Not Work on Certain Webpages

Tags: php, web-crawler

I wrote a program in PHP to find and print all links present on a web page.  It also goes inside any links it found and does the same. My problem is that in some sites (like Youtube) it won't print the links, or follow inside them.

Here is my main code:

```
function echo_urls($site_address){

    if(check_valid_url($site_address)){
        $site = new site();
        $site->address = $site_address;
        $site->full_address = "<a href=\"$site_address\">$site_address</a>";
        $site->depth = 0;

        $queue = new queue();

        $queue->push($site);
        array_push($queue->seen,$site->address);

        $depth = 0;

        while(($site = $queue->get_first())){
            $depth++;
            echo $site->depth." : ".$site->full_address."<br>";
            $queue = push_links($site->address,$queue,$depth);
        }
    }
    else;
}
function push_links($site_address,$queue,$depth){
if($depth<4){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site_address);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        if( $result ){
            preg_match_all( '/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU', $result, $list);

            $list = $list[0];

            foreach( $list as $item ) {
                if(!(empty($item)))
                if($result = get_all_string_between($item,"href=\"","\"")){
                    if((array_search($result[0],$queue->seen))==false){
                        $site = new site();
                        $site->address = $result[0];
                        $site->full_address = $item;
                        $site->depth = $depth;
                        $queue->push($site);
                        array_push($queue->seen,$site->address);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $queue;
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem to what is not working exactly? And explain us precisely what _woun't answer_ means? Is the problem happening with cURL, the DOM parser, something else? Do you get any error message?

Comment: NOt all pages are crawlable. - you're not executing javascript, so any pages that load content via that route are going to be invisible to your crawler

Comment: thanks Mathieu Imbert I mean if I send any address to echo_urls function like http:\\google.com it print all links in google but if I send http:\\youtube.com it wouldn't print any link

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the page manually using `curl` from the CLI, and looking at the HTML you get back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell by looking at a couple of functions, but my guess is:

1. YouTube is blocking you
2. This part `if($depth<4){` is stopping `push_links` from executing because it might be returning FALSE

Also, don't use RegEx for this. Use something like [The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use PHPQuery for crawling the sites. It's very simple

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/